# Rotate while in Layout View

Tags: arcgis-9.3

I am using ArcGIS 9.3 without any extensions.  How do you get your map to rotate?  I've done it before but it has been awhile and now the "rotate" does not seem to function now.  I've tried using while in edit and non-edit.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the Data Frame > Properties > General > Rotation.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To interactively rotate your data frame, you can also enable the "[Data Frame Tools](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006600000004000000.htm)" toolbar  (see "Working with the Data Frame tools" section in help), which allows you to drag/drop your data frame rotation.

The "Data Frame Tools" work in either data or layout view.