# Is it possible to rotate the entire layout view, not just the data frame?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, layouts

I have a project that requires the use of a CAD-like map template that is Landscape orientation, but with the title block along the right edge, with all the text in it rotated 90 degrees. Something like this:

[image]

Except that the drawing, sheet #, etc. in mine are rotated the same way the Project Name, Drawing Name, etc. are rotated in that example.

I already have this template created, but in Portrait orientation. I could rotate the data frame 90 degrees, render it to PDF, rotate the PDF page back to Lanscape, and it will look like the example above. But what I'd **like** to do is rotate the entire layout view so that my Portrait template is presented to me in Landscape on screen, so I can look at and manipulate the contents of the data frame in the same orientation they'll appear when printed. Rotating all the text elements and text boxes in an ArcGIS layout is a pain and usually requires lots of small adjustments to line everything up properly after it's been rotated, so I'd rather not have to create a new template and rotate everything to match the orientation above.

I don't believe ArcGIS can actually do this, but let me know if I'm wrong..

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18145/rotate-while-in-layout-view

Comment: I don't think there is a tool to do this.  In the amount of time since you posted this question, you probably could have just remade the title block.